# How to replace values in different columns is same sql table

Tags: sql

What would the script be if I wanted to update column b with different values for current values of column A? So in column values currently have different values and we need the final result to be as per below.

P.e.

```
Column(A)        Column(B)
0440                A
04470               A
045102              A
030532              B
03580               B
03240               C
```

etc. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can't understand what you want and what you have please elaborate your question

Comment: This will get closed as is, because it is not clear what you're asking.  Tag the DBMS you are using (ie. Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server), add example data not just expected output, and add whatever query you have attempted so far.